# Libgdx - Collision position - Box2D

Tags: java, collision-detection, libgdx

I'm currently developing my own game but I'm facing a little problem. I am trying to figure out how to get the position of a fixture (collision) between two entities.

For example this:

[image]

(the grey rectangle is the player and the greens is an entity (not moving)).

With this code :

```
        Array<Contact> contacts = levelDatas.world.getContactList();
        try {
            for(Contact contact : contacts) {
                if(contact.getFixtureA().equals(playerBody.getFixtureList().get(0))) {
                    levelDatas.bodyIsWall(contact.getFixtureB().getBody());
                }
                if(contact.getFixtureB().equals(playerBody.getFixtureList().get(0))) {
                    levelDatas.bodyIsWall(contact.getFixtureA().getBody());
                }
            }
        } catch(GdxRuntimeException exp) {
        }
```

I get all the collision between a player and something else. But my problem is that I want to know where the collision is happening (on the left? on the right? bottom? top?). We can see that if there is a collision between 2 entities, a little point is draw. Anyone have a tip to give me the position of the collision?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/get-side-of-fixture-which-is-colliding-box2d/ maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two fixtures collide, there are most of times multiples collisions between them, you can see those collisions with :

```
for (int i = 0; i < contact.getWorldManifold().getNumberOfContactPoints(); i++) {
   contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[i].x;
   contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[i].y;
}
```

1st you check all collsion number, then you will get the X and Y position of the given 'i' index.